# on page load javascript check value from HTML5 webstorage table's field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When my page loads, I create a database with fields and data is successfully loaded in all the fields.

In my webstorage database their is a column `favourite` and its type is integer. when my database is filling data in all fields this, the `favourite` field is field with 0 values.

After this there I display only one button in my page whose code is:

`<img id="fav_image" onclick="addFav()" src="icons/star_fav_empty_icon.png" />`

[image]

When I click this image, it changes the value from 0 to 1 in the `favourite` field in database.

As you see on **id 3** `favourite` value is **1** in **abc table**

[image]

After changing image value, its function is also changed ... 
[image]

... which I'm doing like this:

```
function addFav()
   {
    var pageId = a;     
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql(updateFav,[1,pageId], showEmpty , onError);
        });
    document.getElementById('fav_image').src="icons/star_fav_icon_fill.png";
    document.getElementById('fav_image').setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: 
    removeFav();" );
    }

function removeFav()
   {
    var pageId = a;      
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql(updateFav,[0,pageId], showEmpty , onError);
        });
    document.getElementById('fav_image').src="icons/star_fav_empty_icon.png";
    document.getElementById('fav_image').setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: addFav();"      
    );
    }
```

According to me, everything is working fine here.

I need to check the `favourite` value when page is loaded and show the image and `onClick` function according to the `favourite` value:

- if the value is 0, then show empty star image with the `addFav()` function
- if the value is 1, then show filled star image with the `RemoveFav()` function

I get the `favourite` value from the database using this function:

```
function checkfav()
{
    var cID = a;
    var b;
    var getFavBool = 0;
    //fav.innerHTML = '';
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql(selectfavStatement, [cID], function(tx, result) {
            dataset = result.rows.item(0);
             getFavBool = dataset['favourite'];                            
              b = parseInt(getFavBool,10);
              if(b==1)
              {
              fav.innerHTML = b;
              return b;
              }
              else
              {
                fav.innerHTML = b;
                return b;
              }

          });
        });
}
```

I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to say...

Comment: I solved this problem myself... If you need code then reply here i will write it down here...

Answer (score 0):

I only added the `checkfav()` function whose code is:

```
function checkfav()
{
    //this is a ID to which i want to get the result.
    var cID = a;    
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql("selectfavStatement", [cID], function (tx, result) {
   var len = result.rows.length, i;
   dataset = result.rows;
   for (var i = 0, item = null; i < len; i++){
    item = dataset.item(i); 
        var favID = item['favourite'];

        //now this line is only to show result on HTML page. (optional)
        document.getElementById('fav').innerHTML = item['favourite']; 
        if(favID==1)
        {
           document.getElementById('fav_image').src="icons/star_fav_icon_fill.png";
           document.getElementById('fav_image').setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: addFav();"          );    
        }
        else if(favID==0)
        {
            document.getElementById('fav_image').src="icons/star_fav_empty_icon.png";
            document.getElementById('fav_image').setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: removeFav();" );
        }
   }
 });
});

}
```